# Django: how to use your simple-JWT url path json responce in serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-urls, registration, django-serializer

My serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        exclude = ('password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff',
                   'groups', 'user_permissions')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[
                                   UniqueValidator(queryset=UserModel.objects.all().values_list('email'))])
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'password2')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "Пароли не совпадают!"})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create(email=validated_data['email'],)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user, Response()
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from users.views import UserAPIView, RegisterUserAPIView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView


app_name = 'users'

users_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
users_router.register('users', UserAPIView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(users_router.urls)),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('register/', RegisterUserAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets
from .models import UserModel
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


class UserAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Class based view to register user


class RegisterUserAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

My models.py:

```
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class UserModel(AbstractUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Электронная почта',
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    password = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Пароль',
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
    delivery_address = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Адрес доставки',
        max_length=254,
        blank=True,
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Номер телефона',
        max_length=254,
        blank=True,
    )
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My registration post-method returns only email [image]  How can i override my create function in Register serializer to display email and access token at the same time?
P.S. Now, I get access token from path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'), which is the built-in simple-jwt library path. Its swagger on the picture below:
[image]

I think I need to override create method. And user has to be added in database before getting access token, otherwise token won't found a user.

Comment: 123455678912345

Answer (score 1):

#views.py

```
class LoginWithUserDetail(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

#serializers.py

```
class CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

  def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super(CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
    if self.user.is_active is not True:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"message": "User is not active."})
    data.update({
        'username': self.user.username,
        'email': self.user.email,
        'mobile_number': self.user.mobile_number
    })
    return data
```

you need to overwrite the serializer with that extra information with acess_token and refresh_token

link for repo: https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy/

Comment: Now POST /token/ looks like this:
request
{
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string"
}

response
{
  "email": "string"
}. And register is the same, no access toke in its response

Comment: check self.user contain your desired fields or not if have put them in data

Comment: these desired fields displayed in POST /token/ response. I need access_token from POST /token/ to be displayed in POST /register/ response

Comment: can you please show me an example?

Comment: POST /token/ should be the same (with acces and refresh token response), but POST /register/ should have response with additional access_token field, besides email ( { "email": "string", "access": "string" } ), which he can get from POST /token/

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by overriding the RegisterUserApiView post method:

```
class RegisterUserApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    data = {
        'email': user.email,
        'access_token': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```